# How is this patent legal?

Tags: us6630507, marijuana, cannabis

Cannabinoids as antioxidants and neuroprotectants.

Marijuana is a schedule 1 drug according to the federal govermnet but this patent says they own the patent on a natural substance, process and plant- cannabinoids

Answer (score 4):

Patents *can* be obtained for things that are not legal. A patent does *not* mean you can do it. It means you can keep others from doing it. Also, something occurring in nature cannot be patented in its natural state. All of these claims start off with "A method of treating diseases . . . ".  That is not at all claiming a natural substance.

Answer (score 1):

You can take already existing things (natural, man-made) and patent new uses. There are many patents and pending patents for THC or marijuana.